# Splash Screen Not Closing When Using DialogResult VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, splash-screen

I have added a Splash Screen to my VB.Net Windows Form Application and set the Splash Screen in the properties. The Splash Screen shows as expected but it will not go away.

I have narrowed this down to the fact that at the beginning of my Main Forms Load Event I have some code which basically looks in My.Settings to see if a certain setting has an empty string and if it does, it then shows a message box with yes No Buttons

If yes is chosen, then show Frmpreferences
If No is chosen then Exit the sub

```
    Dim DSDLocationMessage As String = "Messagebox to go here"
    Dim DSDLocationTitle As String = "messagebox title to go here"
    Dim DSDLocationResult As DialogResult

    If My.Settings.DSDFastLaneLocation = String.Empty Then
        DSDLocationResult = MessageBox.Show(DSDLocationMessage, DSDLocationTitle, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If DSDLocationResult = vbYes Then
            Me.Hide()
            FrmPreferences.Show()
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
```

If I remove this code then the Splash screen behaves normally. Why does the above code prevent the Splash Screen from closing and is there a work around as this is driving me nuts.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that if you remove the IF.THEN.. code block after the MessageBox.Show, then it works normally?  Or do you mean that if you remove ALL of the code above (including the MessageBox.Show) then it behaves normally?

Comment: If I remove all the code above it works normally

Comment: With the code in: 1) does the message box appear?  2) Does the splash screen stay up regardless of whether you click Yes or No in the message box?

Comment: With the code in place, I am not even seeing the MessageBox because the Splash Screen shows and never Closes

Comment: Is it possible that the Splash Screen is hiding/covering the Message Box?

Comment: Yes, the Splash Screen was hiding the MessageBox. Now I can see the MessageBox, the splash screen does go away when I press yes or no. I was under the impression that the splash screen should close and then the MessageBox shows

Comment: I ask because I suspect that what's happening here is that the thing that closes the Splash screen runs *after* the Main Load event, but your Main Load event is getting stuck because the MessageBox.Show is never getting clicked (because it is opening *behind* your Splash screen).  Kind of a visual deadlock...

Comment: Move that code to the `Shown` event.

Comment: You need to tag us like @Jimi, to be sure that we see it...

Comment: @Jimi Moving the code fixed it. Can you briefly explain why this fixed it Jimi Please

Comment: Well, the Form with the role of SplashScreen is closed, after a default delay, when the starting Form is done loading. Your MessageBox  prevents the Load event handler to return, so the MessageBox is hidden under the Splash form (which is waiting for the starting Form to end the Load process), since both are presented centered on screen and the MessageBox is *owned* by the starting form, not the Splash screen. You can also handle the Splash form yourself, instead of relying on the automatic feature.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for the explanation